# Closure compiler renames class name

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-closure-compiler

Probably simple question, but I can't find solution. How to prevent jQuery-dependent SomeClassName class from renaming by Closure Compiler?

```
(function($) {

  /**
   * SomeClassName
   * @constructor
   */
  function SomeClassName() {

  }
  SomeClassName.prototype.someFunction = function() {
     alert('somefunction');
  };


  var a = new SomeClassName();
  a.someFunction();

})(jQuery);
```

http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home

Comment: As your code is, it doesn't have any kind of public API, so why do you need to keep the name the same?

Comment: Whether it does or not affects Closure Compiler's behaviour (see Mythril's answer below), so it's an important distinction to make. The code that you've posted above doesn't.

Comment: @NathanMacInnes You wrote: "it doesn't have any kind of public API". Wrong. SomeClassName IS a public function.

Comment: @AndroidDev from outside the closure: `try { new SomeClassName(); } catch(e) { alert('Not defined'); }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Export the Class Name. Google Closure is changing it because it's not public.

```
(function($, exports) {

  /**
   * SomeClassName
   * @constructor
   */
  function SomeClassName() {

  }
  SomeClassName.prototype.someFunction = function() {
     alert('somefunction');
  };


  var a = new SomeClassName();
  a.someFunction();

  exports.SomeClassName = SomeClassName;

})(jQuery, window);
```

Comment: If it is only for external/public use (as in your sample) you can export it at declaration: `SomeClassName.prototype['someFunction'] = function() {}`.

Comment: It is public. Google Closure Compiler just can't see it. But if you run your code as you originally posted it, you are able to access SomeClassName, so it has to be public.

Comment: No, it isn't. The outer function forces the inner names into local scope.